# Keras LSTM Input Transpose

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I'm training a timeseries LSTM model using Keras. I understand that the input to the model has to be in the format: `[samples, timesteps, features]`.

However, when I reverse transpose each input element, so the input now is in the format: `[samples, features, timesteps]` my model accuracy improves significantly, and training time is reduced quite a bit as well. Does anyone have an explanation as to why?

For reference, here are the stats on my training data:

```
samples: 720
timesteps: 256
features: 4
```

So my input tensor should have the shape `[720, 256, 4]` but reshaping to `[720, 4, 256]` produces better results. Why?

Comment: So instead of learning sequences of many features over time, you are learning each feature history separately. Since LSTMs are mostly trained to predict the next step in sequence, instead of trying to predict the next set of features in time series, you are trying to learn to predict what the next feature history is going to look like given what you know of a few other feature histories. You changed what you are learning and your results changed.

Comment: @MadWombat make sense... but my output Tensor remained the same in both examples (as I am trying to predict the a future sequence of length `95` of only 1 feature - i.e. output tensor has shape: `[1,95]`). So technically I am predicting the output as accurately, as the labels are the same in both methods. It is just the input tensor that is shaped differently. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know what your network looks like, so I cannot really tell what is going on. So let me just elaborate a bit on LSTM training, maybe it will help. In an LSTM based networks, you generally have 3 dimensions, batches, features and sequence. Lets say you are using a video as your dataset. Each pixel in a single frame can be treated as a feature. A bunch of consecutive frames is a sequence. And since you might not want to train on the whole video all at once, you split the video into batches of, say, 1000 frames each (to be continued in the next comment)

Comment: So, lets say your video frames are 10x10 pixels (unrealistic, but lets keep the numbers small) and you squish them MNIST style into a vector of 100 values. So your single sequence is 100x1000 in size. You might have a batch of a 100 of these sequences, so your total input shape is 100x1000x100. This is the input your network accepts. LSTM will take each [100, 1000] sequence and feed each 100 value vector at the input in sequence and update weights on both the regular connections and all the gates (continued in the next comment...)

Comment: Depending on how you are using the LSTM, your output can be a sequence of the same size (each time you feed a 100 value vector on the input, you get a 100 value vector on the output for every frame in your 1000 frames) or you could only capture the last output frame (you feed a 1000 frames in and get the last network output). Now, to train you need a loss function. In your comment, you said you have labels. This tells me that you have an output layer. And it looks like it is a one-hot encoded vector.

Comment: Lets say, that we have the same in our hypothetical video example we use the same. Now, no matter what you feed into your network, as long as your input is 100x1000x100, it will treat it as a batch of a 100 sequences of a 1000 vectors of 100 values each. If you split your video correctly, the network will look at each frame in the video, in sequence, and try to learn to match this sequence of frames to your label class. Now, lets say you screwed up your video transformations (continued)

Comment: Lets say you swapped dimensions somewhere. As long as your input has the right shape, the network is going to accept it and produce the same shape of output. But the network might be learning a completely different thing. I cannot edit previous comments, but lets say you have sequences of 100 frames instead of 1000. If you swap the two dimensions, instead of ending up a single frame consisting of a 100 pixels in a sequence of a 100 frames, you end up with a sequence of changes to the same pixel out of a 100 pixels (continued)

Comment: Since the shape stays the same, your network is going to accept it as valid input. But instead of looking at the series frames in a video, it is now looking at one pixel at a time, but with a history of its last 100 changes. The output stays the same shape and the loss function will work and the network will try to learn to predict things, but it is not learning the same thing. If all you want to do is classify existing videos, you don't care. But if you ever want to classify video in real time, you might be in trouble, since now your network is not training to learn time based sequences.

Comment: @MadWombat I think that makes sense. Let me add some more color. I have a timeseries dataset of 4 features. Each input data is shaped `(256,4)` as I have 256 timesteps in each input example. I have 721 training examples. My output tensor is of shape `(1,95)` which predicts 95 subsequent timesteps of 1 feature. What I am wondering is why the accuracy and speed greatly increased with a simple transpose of the input tensor.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my rather long comments, the answer is "because you are not learning the same thing". Frameworks like tensorflow and keras attempt to make training and using networks convenient, so as long as your inputs are at least approximately the right shape, the framework will try its best to feed the data into the network. But the network has no way to interpret the data you feed into it. It is up to you to make sure that what you are feeding into the network makes sense in the context of your data. No matter what data you send and what labels you use, the network will do its best to learn a mapping between the data and the labels. And it might succeed. Just because the pattern you are trying to learn makes no sense doesn't mean it cannot be learned. So to answer your question, you need to figure out what is the meaning of your input transposition and given that LSTM will treat your data as a sequence of consecutive datapoints, what sequences did you end up learning.

Comment: I think that makes sense. Let me add some more color. I have a timeseries dataset of 4 features. Each input data is shaped `(256,4)` as I have 256 timesteps in each input example. I have 721 training examples. My output tensor is of shape `(1,95)` which predicts 95 subsequent timesteps of 1 feature. What I am wondering is why the accuracy and speed greatly increased with a simple transpose of the input tensor.